# MYSQL Inner Join with IF Statement

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to join several tables in my database.
I need to get account information from the 'accounts' table with the latest meter history on it.
And if an account has no meter history, I want it to show 'meter' related fields as NULL.

Here's my query so far:

```
    SELECT
        accounts.id,
        accounts.account_order,
        acc.id AS accounts_class_id,
        acc.zone,
        acc.book,
        acc.service_class,
        acc.size,
        acc.account_no AS series_no,
        accounts.status,
        application_address.address_line,
        concessionaires.firstname,
        concessionaires.middlename,
        concessionaires.lastname,
        mb.brand_name,
        m.meter_no,
        ms.meter_status
    FROM
        accounts 
    INNER JOIN
        applications 
            ON accounts.application_id = applications.id 
    LEFT JOIN
        application_address 
            ON applications.application_no = application_address.application_no 
    LEFT JOIN
        concessionaires 
            ON applications.concessionaire_no = concessionaires.concessionaire_no 
    INNER JOIN
        accounts_classifications acc 
            ON accounts.id = acc.account
    INNER JOIN meter_history mh
            ON mh.id = (SELECT id FROM meter_history mh2
            WHERE mh2.account_id = accounts.id
            ORDER BY mh2.status_date DESC
            LIMIT 1)
    LEFT JOIN
        meter_status ms
            ON mh.meter_status = ms.id
    INNER JOIN
        meter m
            ON mh.meter = m.id
    LEFT JOIN
        meter_brand mb
            ON m.meter_brand = mb.id 
    WHERE
        acc.book = 1 AND acc.zone = 20 AND applications.status = '6' AND acc.status = '1'
```

This would return only accounts with meter history on it.
Where should I put my IF condition so I get accounts with no history as well, or if that is even possible with my query. Thank you!

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `iNNER JOIN`.

Comment: You clearly know about `LEFT JOIN`, you used it with other tables in the query. Why wasn't it obvious to use it for `meter_status`? Also, once you use `LEFT JOIN meter_status`, you have to use `LEFT JOIN` for all the tables that are dependent on it.